# bash script source: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, scripts, source

I have a script that begin like this

```
#!/bin/bash
VALKYRIE=~/myProjects/valkyrie
source $VALKYRIE/cluster.conf
```

but when I run it it returns 
`line 2: ~/myProjects/valkyrie/cluster.conf: No such file or directory`

but the file exist and when I run `source ~/myProjects/valkyrie/cluster.conf` it runs fine.
Any idea? I set `VALKYRIE` variable elsewhere so hard-code in the path isn't an option.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this will help, but you could try fully quoting the variable, in case there are spaces in ~. Hence, `source "${VALKYRIE}/cluster.conf"`.

Comment: no, it doesn't help.

Comment: Are you saying that running `source ~/myProjects/valkyrie/cluster.conf` works, when you replace the last two lines of the script? (Or from the command line?)

Comment: it works whether from command line or in the script

Comment: I think it's something to do with `~` not expanding properly. When I run your script with an intentionally fake path, the error doesn't say `~`, but expands the path. Can you try replacing the `~` in your script with the absolute path? Also, try running the following in a script `echo ~`.

Comment: you're right, not using `~` did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is that good enough? Should I write it up as an answer, or do you want to use `~` and work out why it doesn't work?

Comment: You could also try `$HOME` instead of `~`.

Comment: The code you show doesn't match the error message. You must have written `VALKYRIE="~/myProjects/valkyrie"` -- quotes would suppress the expansion of the tilde.

Comment: to be exact I used `VALKYRIE=~/myProjects/valkyrie` without quotes inside `~/.pam_environment`

Comment: @Khoi That explains it. `~/.pam_environment` is not a shell script, so it doesn't do the common things you'd expect from a shell, such as tilde expansion and parameter expansion, so neither `~` nor `$HOME` will be replaced. If you move that line to `~/.profile` instead, and add `export ` in front, it should work.

Comment: It's said that the recommended way to add environment variable is through `~/.pam_environment`. Well I don't need to use `~` nor `$HOME`, works for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`~` doesn't appear to be expanding properly. When I run your script with an intentionally fake path, the error doesn't say `~`, but expands the path (i.e. `/home/sparhawk/fakepath` not `~/fakepath`. You could try using `$HOME` instead of `~`, or using the full path in the script instead.

(I'm not sure why `~` doesn't work on your system, as your script works fine for me.)

Comment: When you look at the order that bash performs expansions 
(http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions),
you'll see that tilde expansion happens *before* variable expansion. That's why `$HOME` is better than `~` in a variable

Comment: @glennjackman I'm not sure I understand. Why would priority matter for variables vs. `~`?

Comment: it's not exactly "priority", it's simply what comes first. Consider `x="~/.bashrc"; ls $x` -- in the order of expansions for the "ls" command, bash looks for a tilde and doesn't find one; eventually bash sees a variable and expands it. bash does not go back and look for tildes again, at this point it's just a plain character. and there are no files in the current directory that begin with a tilde.

Comment: Ah okay. I think I get it. I've always wondered why that command fails and `x=~/".bashrc"; ls $x` works. Thanks for the info.

Comment: My path was within the quotes so I had to remove the quotes and it worked.